# cant connect to postgres db - docker swarm

Tags: postgresql, docker, intellij-idea, jdbc, docker-swarm

I have difficulties to connect to my postgresql via IntelliJ. 
I am using this docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
 db:
  image: postgres
  environment:
   POSTGRES_DB: postgres
   POSTGRES_USER: postgres_user
   POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres_password
   PG_DATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdatai
  expose:
   - "5432"
  ports:
   - "5432"
  volumes:
   - /var/lib/postresql/db/
  deploy:
   placement:
    constraints:
     - node.hostname == vmAPT1
```

I put this inside by command:

```
docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml vmAPT1
```

when I use:

```
docker ps
```

I see:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
31d1337a142c        postgres:latest     "docker-entrypoint..."   30 minutes ago      Up 30 minutes       5432/tcp            vmAPI1_db.1
```

And when I am trying simply to connect to db by IntelliJ:

```
jdbc:postgresql://192.168.200.140:5432/postgres
```

I am recieving that connection failed. How to handle that?? I thought that the port is open for connections

Comment: Can you provide the error logs from the server for PostgreSQL?

Comment: It should look similar to: `2017-09-09 18:10:17 UTC [2740-2] postgres_user@postgres FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres_user"`

Comment: @AK47 I can have only logs from docker service logs id_of_service. And they are very poor. I dont see any more possibilities to gain logs, which you are talking about.

Comment: what is the output `docker service ls`

Comment: @xross Your pgdata directory is wrong, it should be `PG_DATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data` or have you initialised your database cluster in `/pgdatai`?

Comment: Thx, already found the problem :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem:
mistake in yml file:
instead of

```
port: 
- "5432"
```

should be:

```
port:
- "5432:5432"
```

Comment: It should be `ports` rather than `port`